# how do I fix python version for freya?

Tags: release-freya, python

I managed to screw up my python by upgrading 2.7.6 to 2.7.13; now the system has 2.7.13; I managed to find out that I can add a file called `allow_downgrade` under `etc/apt/preferences_d/` to downgrade to the factory settings. however this doesn't help me downgrade Python to the original 2.7.6. this solution was originally for Ubuntu. I thought it should work as well.

Is there a way I can still fix the system? I can see that some deps have already been messed up because of this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If the original package is still available somewhere in your repositories, you could do that with

```
sudo apt install -f python=2.7.6
```

After this, you might still have to run `sudo apt install -f` a couple of time to get other dependencies downgraded as well.